How to mock AWS Data Catalog?
I am developing a piece of code that interfaces with AWS Glue Data Catalog.
It does a bunch of DeleteTable, CreateTable, CreateDatabase, DeleteDatabase and that's it. No jobs, no workflows; just 4 API calls.
At the moment I am mocking everything with TestContainers and LocalStack Pro. I need the pro version because provides the Glue mocking service.
I am currently using the trial version but I was wondering if there is better and cheaper way in order to run this tests.
